# Angularjs ng-show directive interprets the 'N' and 'NO' as falsy values

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

It seems that Angularjs ng-show directive interprets the 'N' and 'NO' as falsy values.

In my angular application, I'm displaying data related to a specific country using the following
    `<div ng-show="countryCode">some code</div>` 
I was surprised when I figured out that data related to Norway are not shown. And this is because the country code of Norway is 'NO' which is considered as falsy value !!

I don't know if this is a design choice. but if Yes how you deal with this kind of issues

You can reproduce this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PqcAy/)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually it's a design choice, you can see the responsible function here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/fca7bcaf43af3a4501ea0727d48f606c58d76bcd/src/Angular.js#L961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-show="!!countryCode"` to force the behaviour you want.

---

From reading the code, the behaviour appears to be by design. However, the documentation says:

> if the expression is truthy then the element is shown or hidden
>   respectively

which is only true if the angular developers are using `truthy` to mean something different to its javascript meaning.

Comment: bang, bang.  I love JS. :)

Comment: Could use `ng-hide="!countryCode"` as well.

Comment: `!!` is an accepted idiom to get a boolean representing the truthiness of a javascript value. Good old dynamically typed languages.

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine.  If I came across code like that though I might not know why it was done that way.  Might need a comment added for clarity.

Comment: @JoeGauterin nice trick from logic. indeed booleanValue=!(!booleanValue) Thank you